# How to add memory to create_csv_agent in langchain?

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, langchain

I am trying to add [ConversationBufferMemory](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/memory/types/buffer.html) to the [create_csv_agent](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/agents/toolkits/examples/csv.html) method. My code is as follows:

```
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.agents import create_csv_agent
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
csv_memory = ConversationBufferMemory()
agent = create_csv_agent(OpenAI(temperature=0), file_path, verbose=True, memory=csv_memory)
```

Not too sure how to proceed since the above does not seem to be working correctly, even though no error is thrown. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just add

`print(agent.run(input=input("Question: ")))`

at the bottom

Full script:

````
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.agents import create_csv_agent
from langchain.llms import OpenAI

file_path = "pokemon.csv"
csv_memory = ConversationBufferMemory()

agent = create_csv_agent(OpenAI(temperature=0), file_path, verbose=True, memory=csv_memory)
print(agent.run(input=input("Question: ")))```
````

Comment: If you add print statements to csv_memory both before and after the execution of the agent, you will realize that your method does not work...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution @nb123? I'm having a similar dilemma.

Comment: @Tom I never did for this specific implementation, but found plenty of open source projects on Github that have memory included for documents, including CSVs. Happy to share the list if that helps, but if you are trying to develop from scratch using the above method, unfortunately I cannot be of more help:(

Comment: I managed to resolve it yesterday so all good now. Has memory,  unique chat history ID and ready to go!

Comment: @Tom you got it working, post the working code so that others can learn.